# How use an expression object as input in sum function in R

Tags: r, sum, expression

I want to use the content of my "Input" Object inside my min.rss function but i have the following error :

> Error in sum((input[[1]])) : invalid 'type' (language) of argument

I don't understand why sum is not able to read the content of `input[[1]]` while when i copy/paste the content of `input[[1]]` directly in sum it's working

Here is my code :

```
var = mtcars
var$mpg2 = var$mpg
var$mpg = NULL

mDegree = 10

mList = c()
for (i in 1:mDegree){
  mList = c(mList,paste0(paste0(paste0('var[[',i),']]'),'*'))
}
mListBis = c()
for (j in 1:mDegree){
  mListBis = c(mListBis,paste0(paste0(paste0('par[',j+1),']'),'+'))
}

mChar = "par[1]+"
for (k in 1:mDegree){
  mChar = paste0(mChar,paste0(mList[k],mListBis[k]))
}

mChar = strtrim(mChar, nchar(mChar)-1)
mChar = paste0(mChar,'-',paste0('var[[',i+1),']]')
mChar = paste0('(',mChar,')^2')
input = parse(text = mChar)

min.RSS <- function(data, par) {

  with(data, 
       sum((input[[1]])))
}


#########################################################
#########################################################

(result <- optim(par = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), min.RSS, data = var))
```

My principal objective is to make the following code more responsive :

```
mtcars <- data.frame(mtcars) 
dat=data.frame(y=mtcars$mpg, x=mtcars$wt)
 min.RSS <- function(data, par) { 
with(data, 
      sum((par[1] + par[2] * x - y)^2)) 
} 
(result <- optim(par = c(0, 1), min.RSS, data = dat))
```

Comment: Your expression has things like `par[11]` but `par` only has 10 elements. And `input` is a quoted expression. You need to use `eval()` to actually evaluate it. You can't just pass those as parameters to function and expect them to expand. It seems like you could be doing all this in a much less complicated way with some simple matrix multiplication. Maybe it's better to take a step back and say what you are trying to do rather than having us fix the way you choose to do it.

Comment: Hello MrFlick, 

First of all, thank you for your answer,

My main idea was to make the following code more responsive :

mtcars <- data.frame(mtcars)


dat=data.frame(y=mtcars$mpg, 
               x=mtcars$wt)

min.RSS <- function(data, par) {
  with(data, sum((par[1] + par[2] * x  - y)^2))
}

(result <- optim(par = c(0, 1), min.RSS, data = dat))

i'm trying to find a solution to use it  with more variables, I know it can be more easier to use simple matrix multiplication but i don't know how to do it.. if you can help me please i would appreciate it a lot

Kind regards